# need help creating a non matching regex pattern

Tags: php, regex

i'm trying to create a regex pattern that returns true if a certain word is not found. Ive tried using [^word] but that doesn't match up against a word just the individual characters as they appear.

I need preg_match(using php) to return true cause there are other words that I to match and return true.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular expression to match string not containing a word?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word)

Answer (score 1):

if you are looking for a string within a string (no pattern needed) then use strstr() or stristr()

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!preg_match("/word/", $string)) { // <-- true, if not match
    // code here
}
```